# How to make link inside button accessible to voice over?

Tags: accessibility

I am trying to put link inside a big button. How to make link inside button accessible/readable to voice over

Comment: For an answer specify please -> which target os, -> which target language, -> which gui framework?

Comment: You've said nothing here about what programming language, device, framework, etc. you're using - do you really think you're going to get a useful answer if all you tell us you're doing is "put link inside a big button"?

Comment: How to make Stack Overflow question accessible to answers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is about a button in an HTML document.  Do not put a link into a button, use style attributes to make the link look and feel like a button.

Example HTML and css fragments for a Next link appearing as a button

```css
a.schedule_btn:link {
    color : #101010;
    background-color: #bcc6de;
}

a.schedule_btn:visited {
    color : #101010;
    background-color: #bcc6de;
}

a.schedule_btn:hover {
    color : #ffffff;
    background-color: #9ca6be;
}

.schedule_btn {
    padding-left   : 1em;
    padding-right  : 1em;
    padding-top    : 5px;
    padding-bottom : 5px;
    border         : solid 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#HikeSchedule" class="schedule_btn">
   Next&ensp;&gt;
</a>
```

Comment: Hover styles should be applied to focus as well. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C15.html